# Google maps API map - initialise script in body not head, map not appearing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add a google map to a page which is pre-defined and protected, so I can only add code to the body section. I've put the script at the bottom of the page and used the code for asynchronous loading from google's tutorial but, well, my div remains sadly empty. I suspect the API is not loading but have no clue how to check that. Any ideas please?

Thanks!

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 650px; height: 350px;">
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDOtp_8dtVzG4kEJEzLw7E5bC187DagTRg&sensor=FALSE&callback=initialize";
}

window.onload = function(){loadScript();};

</script>
```

Comment: Perhaps I'm not seeing your whole code, but it looks like you don't call the 'Initialize' function anywhere. What if you tried calling `initialize();` in your `loadScript();` function?

Comment: @jmac, he's specifying `initialize` as the callback parameter, which should execute it when the API script loads

Comment: @duncan ah, apologies, it's tacked on at the end of the script.src line there. Didn't notice.

Answer (score 3):

**1**. you must insert the script-element into the document, otherwise the script will not execute:

```
 function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

**2**.the sensor-parameter(`true` or `false`) must be lowercase

Comment: Thanks Dr. Molle. I made the changes but unfortunately that didn't solve my problem. The code does however work now when I run it in w3Schools Tryit Editor, so there must be something on the page preventing it from loading. Any ideas where I could look?

Comment: Unfortunately I lack the points to up-vote you! Thanks, you got me thinking in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about Dr.Molle's corrections, it occurred to me that I didn't need to load the script via a function since I was writing it near `</body>` anyway. I removed the function loadScript and simply typed the script and voila, success!